# Set up Asterisk on Windows Azure issue with opening port range 10000:20000

Tags: azure, asterisk

we are trying to set up Asterisk on CentOS 6 on Azure, but the problem is that end points can only be opened one by one and there is a limit of 150 in total.
Is there a way to open port range 10000:20000? If so how we do this?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use PowerShell for this

```
$i={numberFrom}
do
{ Get-AzureVM -ServiceName "server1" -Name "server1" | 
  Add-AzureEndpoint -LocalPort $i 
  -PublicPort $i -Name MW3Port$i -Protocol TCP | Update-AzureVM; $i+=1
}
until ($i -gt {numberTo})
```

**Get-AzureVM**

> Synopsis
>       Retrieves information from one or more Windows Azure virtual machines.
>
> Syntax
>       Get-AzureVM [[-ServiceName] ] [[-Name] ] []

**Add-AzureEndpoint**

```
Synopsis
    Adds a new endpoint to a Windows Azure virtual machine.

Syntax
    Add-AzureEndpoint [-Name] <String> [-Protocol] <String> [-LocalPort] <Int32> [-PublicPort <Int32>] -VM <IPersistentVM> [-ACL <NetworkAclObject>] [-DirectServerReturn <bool>] [<CommonParameters>]
```

**Update-AzureVM**

```
Synopsis
    Modifies the configuration of a Windows Azure virtual machine.

Syntax
    Update-AzureVM [-ServiceName] <String> [-Name] <String> -VM <PersistentVM> [<CommonParameters>]
```

Also checkout the following:
[Adding multiple endpoints to your Windows Azure Virtual Machines by using a CSV file](http://fabriccontroller.net/blog/posts/adding-multiple-endpoints-to-your-windows-azure-virtual-machines-by-using-a-csv-file/)

I'm not sure of the current limit {**someone insert a reference here**}, but use the shell to create endpoints until an error.

Answer (score 1):

You not need 10000 ports be opened for asterisk to be operational.

You need ONE port per channel.

So just open 10000-10050 and change in /etc/asterisk/rtp.conf port range.

Answer (score 1):

Considering using Azure's [Instance-level Public IP Address (PIP)](https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-instance-level-public-ip/).

This allows you to bypass cloud endpoints altogether. Instead, you need to configure iptables, which will give you full control.

Currently, PIPs are dynamic IPs. So you will need to use a dynamic DNS service. If you want to use your own domain, you can CNAME to the DDNS.